# How to use the pug2html extension in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, pug, visual-studio-extensions

I installed the ["Pug to HTML" extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ginie.pug2html) on visual studio code. 
I wrote a sample file whose name is "test.pug"
I do not find any way to convert it to an Html code.
When I write pug in the task selector, nothing happens.
I tested on Windows as well as on Linux.

I guess I have to configure something but the help is not clear enough for me.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me to setup this extension.

Thank you

Comment: This is better posted as an issue with the plugin on their [github issues page](https://github.com/giniedp/vscode-pug2html/issues)

Comment: Thank You Lance. I did it.
FYI my firstname is Jean-Marc not Jean :-)

Comment: Hi Jean-Marc, sorry for that mistake in last comment, and glad to know this issue is resolve with answered status :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open your pug file
- Right click it to get options up
- Click on Command Palette (or hotkey ctrl shift p)
- popup comes up, type in pug and click on Pug to html
  It should output a preview.html file with your html code.

Comment: Thank you it works. I was confused between the Command Palette and the "run Task".

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get `Command 'pug2html: Transform' resulted in an error (command 'extension.transformPugToHtml' not found)`

Comment: @geoidesic Check if you've installed the extension. IF you've just installed it, close all your vs code, turn it back on, and test again. Sometimes extensions need a restart.

Comment: @NhonHa on the contrary, uninstalling the extension did the trick.